# Изменить статус заказа из агента Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Мне нужно изменить статус заказа через агента битрикса. В init.php, в своей функции пытаюсь делать так:

```
CSaleOrder::StatusOrder($delivery->order_id, 'F');
```

Это не работает.

На форумах прочитал, что это из-за отсутствия объекта $USER. Но добавление в начале функции:

```
global $USER;
 if (!is_object($USER)) $USER = new CUser;
```

Тоже ничего не дает.

Пробовал так:

```
$arFields = array(
     "STATUS_ID" => 'F'
);
СSaleOrder::Update($delivery->order_id, $arFields);
```

Но это тоже не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что не подключен модуль `sale`.

Попробуй в начале агента указать

```
 \CModule::IncludeModule('sale');
```

Comment: Помогло. Странно - я думал, что битрикс сам включает модуль, если указать его в настройках агента